# Catching String exceptions

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a jTextField restrict integer input in netbeans and I don't know what to do.
I'm doing it like this:

```
private void txtNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    try {
        String j = (String) txtName.getText();
    } catch ("Which Exception to Catch?") {
        if (!txtAge.getText().isEmpty()) {
            jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please enter string values");
            txtAge.setText(txtAge.getText().replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

What should I put on the catch?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: No. I don't want to use Document Filter.

Comment: String j = (String) txtName.getText(); that wont throw an exception because getText() always return a string. there is no need for cast to a string. i think you want to convert the input string to a integer and then a NuberFormatException is thrown when the user input isnt a valid integer.

Comment: No, I want the textfield to deny the input if it is an integer or any non-string input. This is why i'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just test the input against a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) using [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to make sure it's only digits (no need to catch an exception such as a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) - it can be considered bad practice to provoke exceptions to validate conditions).

```
String j = txtAge.getText();
if (!j.matches("\\d+")) { 
    // It is not a number
}
```

If you just want to try to convert to an `Integer` directly and catch an exception you should use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) (it will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input can't be parsed as an `Integer`):

```
String j = txtAge.getText();
try { 
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(txtAge);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    // j isn't a number...
}
```

**EDIT**: There seems to be a little confusion with the answer you provided. In your question the error message was *Please enter integer values*, as if valid input was only digits. In the answer you posted the message was *Please enter String values*.

If you want to validate the input *doesn't* have any numbers, you'll have to use another regex, such as `.*\\d.*"`. If it matches, it means it *has* a digit. Or you could also use `\\D+` to ensure it has one or more *non-digits*.

Comment: Ok, I want to understand it more.

Comment: `\d` is a special flag that matches only digits. `+` means one or more occurrences. You could use `*` if you wanted to match _zero_ or more occurrences (i.e. accepting an empty String). I'd suggest taking a look at the [Java Tutorial's page on Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Wait. I think there's an error on what you've given

Comment: Glad that helped :-) You can also use `\\D+` to match only one or more _non-digits_.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem like this:

```
private void txtNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
String j = (String)txtName.getText();
if ( j.matches("\\d+") && !txtName.getText().isEmpty()) {
jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter String values");
txtName.setText("");
} }
```

Thanks for the ones who tried to help me :)

Comment: There's no need to check for `isEmpty()`. The regular expression is already checking for _at least_ one digit. Also, you could consider upvoting answers that were helpful and [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169503) the one that solved your question. It will help future visitors of the question to have a clearly accepted answer, and will also make it visible to other users that this question has already been given a valid answer.

Comment: So it is ok to press backspace without `isEmpty()`?

Comment: There seems to be a little confusion here. In your question the error message was _Please enter integer values_, as if valid input was only digits. In this answer the message is _Please enter String values_. If you want to validate the input _doesn't_ have any numbers, you'll have to use another regex, such as `.*\\d.*"`. If it matches, it means it _has_ a digit.

Comment: Well, I had trouble editing. Sorry for that.
But what I want is to disable integer entries.

Comment: Then take a look at my edit in the answer. `\\d+` will detect inputs as `1234`, but not `name1`. You should use `\\D+` to match only non-digits.